# Adding headers to fetch, solving cors, running cryptojs client side

Tags: javascript, fetch, node-modules, cryptojs

I'm working on a project where I need first to get a authentication token from a server.

For this I need to send a GET request to the authorisation server with two key-value pairs included in the header: 1/ the client id (const) and 2/ a HMAC SHA1 calculated value based on client ID timestamp and so on.

This is working fine with Postman. (I calculate the sha1 on an online calculator)

Problem 1: (cryptojs client side)
As a node app I included the cryptojs library and the calculation works. But even with RequireJS I can not get cryptojs to run in the browser.

```
Error: Module name "crypto-js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Problem 2: (cors)

Apparently chrome refuses the connection as the server does not accept all incoming connections.
Adding mode: 'no-cors' to the fetch request does not solve the problem.

Problem 3: (headers)

I need to add two key - value pairs to the get request headers. In postman this is no problem but I'm not sure this works with append or just adding them to my headers: { }

I constantly get a server error as if no headers where added.

I have already tried REquireJS for the cryptojs problem.

I have added the headers to a myHeaders object

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('ClientID', CLIENTID);
myHeaders.append('Clientsecret', hashedToken);
```

and also just added the values to:

```
headers: {
...
'ClientID': CLIENTID,
'Clientsecret': hashedToken,
}
```

Both don't seem to help.

My code:

```
function getToken(){

hashedToken = getHashedSecret();  //this won't work client side as    cryptojs can not be loaded
const CLIENTID = "CLIENTID";
const AUTHURL =  "https://authorization.server.com/api/CLIENTID/authorization/";
var TIMESTAMP = getTimeStamp();


const myHeaders = new Headers();
//  myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myHeaders.append('ClientID', CLIENTID);
myHeaders.append('Clientsecret', hashedToken);
 console.log(myHeaders);
let response = fetch(AUTHURL+TIMESTAMP, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    myHeaders,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': '',
    'Host': 'authorization.server.com',
    include: 'ClientID', CLIENTID

  },
  mode: 'no-cors',
 })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
console.log('data');
return data;
}
```

I should get a token from the server

Comment: The only working solution I found was to set up my own node backend with API endpoints which will get the results back without problems and then just use my own intermediary API's.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `https://authorization.server.com` doesn't allow access from your page's origin. Remember that in browsers, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents scripts from one origin from requesting information from other origins by default. (`postman`, not being a browser, is not subject to this restriction). This is so that scripts on Site A (a malicious actor) can't steal your personal information from Site B (perhaps your online banking) by making requests (from your browser, thus with your authentication information) to Site B.

For this to work, **server** code at `https://authorization.server.com` will need to respond to requests from the browser using the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) to allow access from your origin. You **cannot** do it from your client-side code (for obvious reasons).

Alternately, you can run a server on your origin, make the requests to that server, and it can make the requests to `https://authorization.server.com` and pass back the responses to you. Your server, not being a browser, is not subject to the SOP.